# Exec an SQL-Server 2008 stored-procedure from Access, passing a TABLE variable

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, stored-procedures, table-variable, pass-through

I need to pass a table from Access to SQL-server and execute a stored-procedure.

I'm using pass-through queries in Access to do this.

My pass-through query:

```
DECLARE @MyVar TABLE { .....<variables> }

INSERT INTO @MyVar   SELECT *
    FROM [MyTable]

EXEC sproc_test @Myvar
```

My stored-procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_test] 

@MyVar TABLE(....<variables>) 

AS ...<the rest of the sproc>
```

Should this work? I'm getting an "Incorrect syntax near TABLE" error in the stored-procecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accept a TABLE variable as a parameter to a stored procedure, you need to define a table type and specify that as the type in the sproc instead of defining the type as TABLE in your sproc definition

e.g. you'd end up with something like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_test]
    @MyVar MyTableType READONLY
AS
...
```

Check out [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2008/08/27/69298.aspx) for how to define the table type etc.